# Insufficient Privilege issue on Lightning Page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, access, lightning-page

In lightning, the user getting an Insufficient Privilege error on the lightning page for a lightning component.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Does the user have access to the controller class?

Comment: Thanks, Maniac coder. The vf page and controller access were not given to the user.

Answer (score -1):

This issue is resolved by giving vf page and controller access to user.